# Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

No logro encontrar donde se esta reproduciendo esta advertencia ni porque, alguna idea?

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../../../raw-assets/svg/logo.svg';
import line from '../../../raw-assets/svg/line.svg';
import 'whatwg-fetch'; 
import {backendURL, backendPort} from '../../components/connect.js';
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'){
var backend = "";
}else{
  var backend = backendURL +':'+ backendPort;
}
import isMobile from 'ismobilejs';
var Menu = require('react-burger-menu').slide;

class ResponsiveHeader extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      categories: [],
      mobile: 'span',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(backend+'/api/categories')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(categories => {this.setState({categories});
  });
  }

  selectKey(event) {  
    this.setState({ exampleState: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    if(!isMobile.any){
      var control = 'logosection';
    }else{
      var control = 'logosection-mobile';
    }
    
     return ( 
       
      <div className="header">
        <div className={control}>
        <div className="logo" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: xxx }} />
        <div className="line" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: line }} />
        <div className="labs">LABS</div>
      </div>

{isMobile.any &&
       
        <Menu right={1}>
    <div className="check-sidebar">
 <ul>
       <div className="languages-header">
      <p>CODE LANGUAGES:</p>
      </div>
      {
      this.state.categories.map(c =>
<li className="checkbox">
            <input id={c.id} type="checkbox" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} value={c.id}/>
            <label htmlFor={c.id}></label>
            <tag>{c.name}</tag>
</li>
          )
        }
</ul>
</div>


        </Menu>

      }

   
{!isMobile.any &&
      <div className="check">
      <div className="languages-header">
      CODE LANGUAGES:
      </div>
      {
      this.state.categories.map(c =>
<span className="checkbox">
            <input id={c.id} type="checkbox" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} value={c.id}/>
            <label htmlFor={c.id}></label>
            <tag>{c.name}</tag>
</span>
          )
        }
      </div>
       }
      </div>

    );
   }
   onChange (e) {
    this.context.applyFilters(parseInt(e.target.value));
  }

}

ResponsiveHeader.contextTypes = {
  applyFilters: React.PropTypes.func
};


export default ResponsiveHeader;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La importancia de esto, es que recordemos que React usa un virtual DOM para luego hacer un diff con el DOM real, y conocer que elemento fue actualizado.

Que tiene que ver todo esto con los Key??? Si no le colocas un key al momento de generar el listado y haces un cambio a algun de los hijos el virtual DOM entendera que hiciste un update a todos y los re-renderizara, por esto es necesario colocar un key, para ayudarlo y ganar tiempo de performance.

Como dice Alejandro, con tan solo colocar un `key = {{algunvalornorepetido}}` se soluciona.

Comment: Mhm es posible Wilfredo, tu te refieres a por ejemplo en el array.map donde hago un listado de checkboxes? Ahi deberia ponerle un key a?

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni Si en cada uno de los .map deberias tener un key.

Comment: Algo como esto? <span className="checkbox" key={randomnumber}>

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni Si, pero recuerda que es un randomnumber que no se repita.

Answer (score 0):

Este error ocurre cuando estas creando un listado de elementos en react y no les agregas un "key" diferente para cada uno de ellos, según recuerdo.

creo que ResponsiveHeader  esta agregando elementos dentro de si mismo, tiene meses que no toco react, pero si vas a crear componentes hijos asegurate de que cada hijo tenga un "key" similar a

```
key = {{algunvalornorepetido}}
```

Para cada uno de los elementos hijos que crees dentro de ese Componente